# Multiplicação de parâmetro e variável com diferentes números de índices

Tags: python

Boa noite,

Estou fazendo uma implementação de um modelo matemático de otimização no Python 3.4. Preciso fazer uma multiplicação de um parâmetro "Lambda" indexado em i,j,tt e uma variável "x" indexada em i,t. A multiplicação está contida em um somatório de i,j,tt e t. No entanto, ao implementá-la no Python e tentar resolver o problema pelo Cplex tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexError: Inconsistent arguments

Parte do código com o erro

```
dat.IT = [(i,t) for i in dat.I for t in dat.T[i]]


nx = ["x(" + str(i) + "," + str(t) + ")" for (i,t) in dat.IT]


Lambda = [[[0.0 for t in dat.T[j]] for j in dat.I] for i in dat.I]
```

Ao declarar a função objetivo do problema:

```
sp.variables.add(obj = [-Lambda[i][j][tt] for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for tt in dat.T[j] for t in range(max(0, tt - dat.p[i][0] - dat.SETUP[i][j][0] + 1), min(tt + dat.p[j][0] + dat.SETUP[j][i][0] - 1, dat.h[i] - dat.p[i][0] + 1) + 1)], names = nx)
```

Tenho certeza que o erro consiste nesta multiplicação.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, poste o código para que possamos ver o problema.

Comment: Editei com parte do código...Obrigada!

Comment: Nesta linha, da pesquisa operacional, `sp.variables.add(obj = [-Lambda[i][j][tt] for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for tt in dat.T[j] for t in range(max(0, tt - dat.p[i][0] - dat.SETUP[i][j][0] + 1), min(tt + dat.p[j][0] + dat.SETUP[j][i][0] - 1, dat.h[i] - dat.p[i][0] + 1) + 1)], names = nx)`, não faltou o `else` do `if` na _list comprehension_? Caso contrário, a dimensão em índice `tt` reduz de 1

Comment: Minha primeira dica seria tirar essas compreensões de lista tanto da declaração de `Lambda` quanto do argumento `obj` abaixo, e no seu lugar botar os loops `for` próprios. Desse jeito, fica extremamente difícil de ler e entender o código e é bem possível que você mesma veja o problema fazendo essa reorganização. Compreensões servem bem pra diminuir verbosidade em coisas óbvias, e não são uma boa ideia se prejudicam significativamente a legibilidade do código. Em geral uma boa regra é não aninhar duas compreensões; no `obj`, sua expressão aninha 4!

Comment: A declaração de `Lambda` dá pra entender; ela está inicializando a matriz com zeros. Mas essa linha da otimização tá difícil de entender! Ainda mais que falta um `else` ali, eu acho.

Comment: Não falta um else, somente contabilizo o valor de Lambda[i][j][tt] na função objetivo se i != j.